# Autoloading a separate, Laravel application into Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, psr-4

I'm writing an API for an existing Laravel application using Lumen. So as to allow the API's controllers to access the Laravel app's models, I've added the Laravel app as a git submodule, and set it to autoload into the "Main" namespace via the composer.json file:

```
"psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Main\\": "main/app/"
    }
```

This works fine, but I wanted to ask what impact this will have on memory usage. Is the entire Laravel app being loaded into memory (thus causing a performance drop), or is the Lumen app just being told "where to look" when a Main\Model class is referenced?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I did - I answered the question but forgot to come back and accept it. Classes are loaded ad-hoc.

Comment: How efficient is it to load the entire Laravel APP into Lumen? I asked around and everyone said to avoid this?

Comment: @AlexLacayo: Actually load it all into memory? Every bit of it that your Lumen app doesn't use = wasted memory. Fortunately, if you load it as I described, this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this process uses standard PHP autoloading functionality under the hood, classes are loaded ad-hoc if not already defined, rather than them each being loaded initially.